# Set specific Frame for Background Color by Cell click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have the following Custom Cell. On the left is a blue label with an image on it, and on the right side a label with some text. No i want that the cell gets highlighted when i click on it, BUT only the **white** part behind the label should get highlighted, not the whole cell with the blue label and the image, any ideas?

I tried something like this:

```
categorieCell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, categorieCell.frame.size.width, categorieCell.frame.size.width)];

categorieCell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

[image]

Comment: Override `setSelected:animated` changing the property you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the cell to be highlighted as a result of the selection, just set the cell's selectionStyle property to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone. That will disable overall cell's highlight when it gets selected.

In tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method apply the following code:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

After that you can change cell background upon the cell gets selected.

In tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *categorieCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    categorieCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Don't forget to change cell background when it gets deselected in willDeselectRowAtIndexPath: